# openpyxl append to the right

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm pretty new to openpyxl, and got a little problem

I am looping through a list and for each item I add a heading and some data. 
My problem is that for each item I go trough, i want to add the "same" data to the right, not top down like the .append method..

Don't know if it makes sense.

an example

```
for agreement in agreements:
    n1 = wb.active

    n1.append([
        make_cell(n1, agreement.name, bold=True),
    ])

    n1.append([
        'Account Number',
        'Account Name',
        'Total DKK',
    ])

   for ....
       n1.append(....)
```

for each agreement i want to add the "same" data to the right, and not upside down.

how to do that?

what i want..

```
headline                headline                headline        
Account Number  Account Name    Total DKK       Account Number  Account Name    Total DKK       Account Number  Account Name    Total DKK
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do but might use either `cell.offset` or `ws.iter_rows` to do this. A bit more work on your behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: ... add the "same" data to the right, not top down like the `.append` method

You have to use `ws.append(...)` anyway.

First you need a `Workbook` Instance:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
```

> > Don't use `n1 = wb.active` inside your `for ...` loop.
> >     You have to get the active Worksheet only **once**.
> >
> > ```
> > for agreement in agreements:
> >     n1 = wb.active
> > ```

```
ws = wb.active
```

> > You want to add **x** Header per Row to the right, so you can't use `.append(...)`.
> >
> > ```
> >     n1.append(['Account Number', 'Account Name', 'Total DKK',])
> > ```

Before you `.append(...)` your Row Column Values, you have to create a List with your expected Values.
For example:

```
HEADER = ['Account Number', 'Account Name','Total DKK']    
listOfColumnValues = []

# Extend listOfColumnValues with HEADER as many times you need
for _ in range(3):
    listOfColumnValues.extend(HEADER)

print("{}".format(listOfColumnValues))
ws.append(listOfColumnValues)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> ['Account Number', 'Account Name', 'Total DKK', 'Account Number', 'Account Name', 'Total DKK', 'Account Number', 'Account Name', 'Total DKK']
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice:4.3.3.2***